# Saperate PostgreSQL db for each client, with automated migrations on creating client on single Django app and on same server

Tags: python, django, postgresql

```
client_obj = Client.objects.create(name='client1')

status = create_database('client1')

def create_database('client1'):
    con = None
    dbname = 'client1'
    con = connect(dbname='postgres', user='***', host = 
    'localhost', password='***')
    con.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE 
    datname = '{}' ".format(dbname))

    exists = cur.fetchone()
    if not exists:
        cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + dbname)
        print "DATABASE NOT EXISTS"
    else:
        print "DATABASE EXISTS"

 cur.close()
 con.close()
```

How to make migrations automated once the db has been created? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + dbname)
```

I created an empty database with initial migrations and copy 
    it each time by using the command:

```
cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE {} WITH TEMPLATE created_db'.format(dbname))
```

Now there no need of dynamic migrations to the newly created db.