# Serving separate database per user django

Tags: python, django, database

i am creating database according this now: [Saperate PostgreSQL db for each client, with automated migrations on creating client on single Django app and on same server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55312779/8101557)

Now I want to serve the db per user. We can return db from db routers only if they exists in the `DATABASES` varriable in the settings file.

Does anybody know how to serve db which are created on server but not added in `settings.py`, which will be according to the logged in user.
There will be a main db for user, in which their relations with their db name is saved.

```
Settings.py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app.router_middleware.DataBaseRouter']
DATABASES = {'default':
    {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'abc',
    'USER': 'xyz',
    'PASSWORD': '*****',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

import django
django.setup()
from Client.views import ALL_DB
DATABASES.update(ALL_DB)


Client.views
ALL_DB = { x.db_name: {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': x.db_name,
    'USER': 'xyz',
    'PASSWORD': '****',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
 } for x in Client.objects.all()}

router_middleware.py

db_name = 'default'
class RouterMiddleware(CoreSessionMiddleware):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated() :
            user = request.user
            if ClientEmployee.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
               client_employee = ClientEmployee.objects.get(user=user)
               db_name = client_employee.client.db_name

class DataBaseRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    return db_name

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    return db_name
```

Comment: you can start [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/)

Comment: the first thing i am facing is that, db_name is not updating in router_middleware.py. Second thing i want to know that is it good idea to use a variable in that file?

Comment: if u want to map user-db I would suggest hold central db with mapping user-db-credentials